# Accessing Header inside react Component file

Tags: react-native, header, react-navigation

can someone help with how to access the header from the actual component in react-navigation-6?
I am trying to set the title based on some data in the component:
example: how can I access this A.js file

```
A.js
const A = (props)=>{
       return <Text>Hello World</Text>
}
export default A
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **navigation.setOptions** like below

```
const A = (props)=> {
  useEffect(() => props.navigation.setOptions({title: 'new title'}), []);
  return <Text>Hello World</Text>
}
export default A
```

Ref : [Updating options with setOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions)